# PHP Function to convert URL

Tags: php

I'm new to php. I really need your help to write a function to convert below URL

From orginal URL: `http://www.domain.com/blahblah/**ID**/**FileName**.html`

To new URL `http://statics.domain.com/download/**ID**/**Filename**.mp4`

I want to get **ID** and **Filename** in the new URL. Can anyone help me to do with this?

Comment: Is this same for all URLs? **`http://www.domain.com/blahblah/`** ?

Comment: Yes, It is same for all URLs

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dirty way which work :

```
$url  = "http://www.domain.com/blahblah/ID/FileName.html";
$replace = array("http://www.domain.com/blahblah/", ".html");
$by   = array("http://statics.domain.com/download/", ".mp4");


$newurl = str_replace($replace, $by, $url);
```

It's basicaly replace what you want by...what you want. But nothing more, and I'm pretty sure a better answer is possible technicaly-writing. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what about ID and Filename?

Comment: You can let the ID and the FILENAME inside the $url variable. The STR_REPLACE function does just replace what is written and let the other caracter where there are.

Comment: I'm using this, I think it's simple:


`function converturl($url){
 if(preg_match('/.*domain.com\/.*\/(.*?)\/(.*).html/is', $url, $id)){
  $newurl = 'http://statics.domain.com/download/'.$id[1].'/'.$id[2].'.mp4';
 }else{
  $newurl = 'URL is not support';
 }
 return $result;
}`

Comment: You can also test this :
function converturl($url)
{
 $replace = array("http://www.domain.com/blahblah/", ".html");
 $by = array("http://statics.domain.com/download/", ".mp4"); 
 return $newurl = str_replace($replace, $by, $url);
}

Didn't try, but seems to work.

Comment: If I remember, preg_match is a more consuming - ressourcely-writing - than str_replace, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A hack way is to [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string by `/` and take last two element of array. Second last element would be an **ID** where as last element would be a **filename**.

You will need to perform [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) on filename to remove last `.html` characters from string.

This is how you do it.

```
<?php

$url="http://www.domain.com/blahblah/ID/FileName.html";
$parts=explode("/",$url);
$totalparts=sizeof($parts);

$id=$parts[$totalparts-2];
$filename=substr($parts[$totalparts-1], 0, -5);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/659950

Answer (score 0):

Solved. This is simple and works.

```
function converturl($url){
    if(preg_match('/.*domain.com\/.*\/(.*?)\/(.*).html/is', $url, $id)){
        $newurl = 'http://static.domain.com/download/'.$id[1].'/'.$id[2].'.mp4';
    }else{
        $newurl = 'URL is not support';
    }
    return $newurl;
}
```